# How can i drag object and drop it inside three.js Mesh?

Tags: jquery-ui, canvas, three.js, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

This is what i have tried yet :

```
    $( ".box" ).draggable({
      helper:'clone',
      start: function( event, ui ) {
        back.material.map = new THREE.Color(0xeeeeee);
        back.material.needsUpdate = true;
      },
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
        back.material.map = texture;
        back.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
    $("canvas").droppable({ // here I've selected canvas for dropping element
        accept:".box",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          var item = $(ui.draggable).clone();
          $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").append(item);
          hanger1();  
       }
   });
```

Basically i want to drag element from outside the `three.js` Scene and drop it inside canvas over a `three.js mesh`. i am using `jQuery UI Draggable` and `Droppable` in which i can only drop element inside html DOM only, but i want to drop it over `three.js mesh`.

how can i make it possible? 
 
If you can do this. so i will highly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i make it possible?

One possible approach you can try it is the usage of `CSS2DRenderer` like demonstrated in this official example: https://threejs.org/examples/css2d_label

When inspecting the code, you will see that the labels are rendered via HTML/CSS. So when a DOM element is dragged over the canvas and dropped, you wrap it into an instance of `CSS2DObject` and add it to your scene graph as a child of your target mesh.

If you need to determine which mesh was hovered by the mouse cursor, you can use basic raycasting. Meaning you can compute mouse coordinates in an `mouse` event listener like so:

```js
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

and then use these coordinates to setup the raycaster like so:

```js
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
```

The raycaster is then ready for intersection tests with your scenes.

Comment: how will i implement css2drenderer? please help!

Comment: Sorry, but nobody will provide a complete solution for you. You have to figure out by yourself how to work with `CSS2DRenderer`. The mentioned example should provide enough code to study the logic.